# exposed filter default values from user fields

Tags: views

How can i set the default value of exposed filter for a view with the current logged in user profile checkboxes?

There can be multiple choices.

Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please provide more details about your current implementation. There are at least 3 ways to get some checkboxes on user profile page, for example.

Comment: Hi, you missunderstood. I have that checkboxes but i want to get the value from there(from checkboxes) and make this value the default for an exposed filter. Ex. If current logged in user has checked the management well the exposed filter default should be the managment articles in articles view. DO you get now?

Comment: No I didn't. But the way you implemented checkboxes determines where their data is stored. And this determines how to access data to use in another part of CMS, like filters.

Comment: oh i get it. I implement that checkboxes based on a field term reference from a vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
function custommodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
  if($form['#theme'][0] == 'views_exposed_form__article__page_1'){
      $form['ct']['#options']['All'] = 'All Article';
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i dont think is what i need. Please see above the more detailed case.

Comment: here I just trying to show you this hook only. Use this hook in your module and do the functionality what ever you want (Set default values for filters according to the user).

Answer (score 0):

```
 function mymod_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if (! _mymod_isFormSubmit()) {
 //exposed filters form hasn't submitted so I am using values from user entity
 global $user;
 $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
 foreach(_mymod_getFiltersMapping() as $filterName => $fieldName ) {
  $tids = array();
  foreach($wrapper->{$fieldName}->value() as $term) {
    $tids[] = $term->tid;
 }
 $form_state['input'][$filterName] = empty($tids) ? 'All' : reset($tids);
}
```

}
}

i have this code but did not works..